# javascript Logical Operators don't do function when page equals to X

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, operators

I dont want to do the if statement when on pageAge OR ON pageMore. When i go to pageAge it works it doesn't execute the script but when I go to pageMore it does. I'm not sure what operator to use in this situation. When I put pageMore before the `||` it works on that page but not on the othe one.

```
if ( top.location.pathname != pageAge || pageMore) {
  //if not verified go to connect
  $("body").css("display", "none");
  if (age === null && top.location.pathname != pageConnect) {
     window.location.href = pageConnect;
  }
  //if to young go to age page while cookie is found (1day)
  if (age == toYoung) {
      window.location.href = pageAge;
  }
  //if already verified go to like page.
  if (age == legal && top.location.pathname === pageConnect) {
      window.location.href = pageLike;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be:

```
if ( top.location.pathname != pageAge && top.location.pathname != pageMore)
```